# JQuery UI Tooltip with data attributes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm attempting to use HTML5 data attributes to store and display content for a tooltip.

I'm using JQuery UI for the tooltip.

I've read the documentation, but haven't figured out how to program the right selector and display the custom data.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/QsEJk/2/

**HTML:**

```
<span class="info-icon"
    data-title="custom title"
    data-desc="custom description">
</span>
```

**JS:**

```
$( '.info-icon' ).tooltip({
    content: function() {
        return 'Title: ' + $( this ).data('title') +
               ' Description: ' + $( this ).data('desc');
    }
});
```

Comment: First, you should write `ready(function() {` instead of `ready({`. Second, you should add your jQuery UI theme's CSS file as an external resource to your fiddle (and maybe in your page also). The rest of the code looks fine.

Comment: Whoops, I just omitted it since fiddle takes care of that.

Comment: Well, nope. jsFiddle handles the inclusion of the jQuery UI scripts, but not of its CSS files.

Comment: Made changes and no dice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need the `items` option

```
$(".info-icon").tooltip({
    items: "[data-title], [data-desc]",
    content: function () {
        return 'Title: ' + $(this).data("title") + ' Description: ' + $(this).data('desc');
    }
});
```

http://api.jqueryui.com/tooltip/

**Edit:**

`[data-title],[data-desc]` will work if either attribute is on the `.info-icon`  span.

`[data-title][data-desc]` will require both attributes specified for the tooltip to work.

Comment: Or maybe `[data-title][data-desc]` since the content function uses both attributes?

Comment: Hmm, the items option makes the API a bit confusing, but thank you!

Comment: Why do you need the function&return to specify the content? Why doesn't
"content: $(this).data('text')" this work? Can you please explain? Thank you!

Comment: @lehel `content` is a callback delegate function. The plug-in expects to run `content` as a function.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer worked for me but in my case I wanted this applied to many items on the page so didn't want a variable for every one. Instead I used this:

```
        $(".help").each(function() {
            $(this).tooltip({
                content: $(this).data('help')
            });
        });
```

This applies the data-help content to every .help item on the page.

Comment: It works on multiple items by default.Please see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QsEJk/21/